# Thread starvation deadlock example

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, deadlock, synchronized

In the book Effective Java by Joshua Bloch, there is this example (item 81):

```
// Simple framework for timing concurrent execution
public static long time(Executor executor, int concurrency,
Runnable action) throws InterruptedException {
    CountDownLatch ready = new CountDownLatch(concurrency);
    CountDownLatch start = new CountDownLatch(1);
    CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(concurrency);
    for (int i = 0; i < concurrency; i++) {
        executor.execute(() -> {
            ready.countDown(); // Tell timer we're ready
            try {
                start.await(); // Wait till peers are ready
                action.run();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } finally {
                done.countDown(); // Tell timer we're done
            }
        });
    }
    
    ready.await(); // Wait for all workers to be ready
    long startNanos = System.nanoTime();
    start.countDown(); // And they're off!
    done.await(); // Wait for all workers to finish
    return System.nanoTime() - startNanos;
}
```

It then says:

*The executor passed to the time method must
allow for the creation of at least as many threads as the given concurrency level, or
the test will never complete. This is known as a thread starvation deadlock
[Goetz06, 8.1.1].*

I am not sure why this would deadlock, e.g. with 1 one thread and two tasks. Do you have an example of a way it could deadlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** : The `concurrency` variable specifies the number of tasks to be executed by the threads in the [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) thread pool passed as parameter of the method `time`. **A deadlock occurs if those tasks are not executed by different threads.**

From the [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) documentation one can read:

> A CountDownLatch is initialized with a given count. **The await methods
> block until the current count reaches zero** due to invocations of the
> countDown() method, after which all waiting threads are released and
> any subsequent invocations of await return immediately.

Equipped with this information, let us imagining that each task is indeed be executed by a different thread. So each thread used from the `Executor` to run the parallel work:

```
() -> {
            ready.countDown(); // Tell timer we're ready
            try {
                start.await(); // Wait till peers are ready
                action.run();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } finally {
                done.countDown(); // Tell timer we're done
            }
        }
```

will call first:

```
ready.countDown();
```

and then `wait` in `start.await();` for the *master* thread to call `start.countDown();` (which is the only thread doing it). However, before doing so, the *master* thread is waiting on:

```
ready.await();
```

for the remains threads to call `ready.countDown();` `concurrency` times. So that the `master` thread can resume its work. Therefore, if each of those tasks are not executed by `concurrency` separate threads, those threads will wait for the *master* thread that in turn is waiting for them as well, hence a deadlock and the statement:

> The executor passed to the time method must allow for the creation of
> at least as many threads as the given concurrency level, or the test
> will never complete.

So regarding your question:

> I am not sure why this would deadlock, e.g. with 1 one thread and two
> tasks. Do you have an example of a way it could deadlock?

So let us say that `concurrency=2`, and you have a thread on the `Executor` pool and the *master* thread. The *master* thread calls:

```
ready.await();
```

which was initialized as follows:

```
CountDownLatch ready = new CountDownLatch(concurrency);
```

therefore `ready.countDown();` needs to be called at least twice. However, there is only one thread on the Executor pool that calls `ready.countDown();` only once and then waits at:

```
start.await();
```

for the *master* thread to call `start.countDown();`, but that thread is still waiting on `ready.await();`. So both threads are waiting on each other, which leads to a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

A simple invocation that would deadlock:

```
time(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1), 2, () -> System.out.println("Hello world"));
```

Here, an executor with just 1 thread is passed in. Since `concurrency` is 2, the one thread waits on the "Tell timer we're ready" line for another thread to decrease the counter again.

But there is no other thread to decrease the counter, because there's only one thread. So the only thread is blocked waiting.